How some auxiliary information influence the CDH assumption?
I am proposing a multi-party group-key agreement protocol in my paper, which can be seen as an extension of the classic Diffie Hellman bipartite group key agreement. However, how to formalize the security proof of this protocol is very challenging, so I have to come here for help. The first step in proving the security is to prove that given $g ^ x$, $g ^ y$, $g^{\left(x^2\right)}$, $g^{\left(y^2\right)}$, calculating $g^{\left(xy\right)}$is a hard problem.Thank you!

Show How to Efficiently Solve the Computational Diffie-Hellman Assumption given an Algorithm that Solves the Square-DH Problem

@kelalaka: doesn't quite work: that algorithm assumes that we can also recover the value $g^{{(a+b)}^2}$; that's not given
